# Is it possible to create a custom login page for your own Wi-Fi hotspot?

Tags: wifi

How do I create my own open Wi-Fi hotspot/access point with a custom login page similar to those found in commercial hot-spots?

The page would be accessible using Windows or [iOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_%28Apple%29), and users would have to accept terms of use, or submit payment details, or enter a username and password before being able to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called a Captive Portal. Basically, it will intercept the first http connections, display the terms etc, require the user to accept them or use a password etc. There are some open source ones available. Don't forget that if the network is unencrypted all users can easily be sniffed/hijacked even if there is a captive portal.

Answer (score 2):

[NoCatNet](http://nocat.net/) provides a **captive portal** solution, which is the technique you are looking for.

Google searches for "captive portal" should point you to other solutions for your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

But you can allow access to the Internet via a firewall and/or web proxy base on details entered on a web page. There's a whole lot of stuff involved here which mostly spans what's covered in Stack Overflow and Server Fault - and is perhaps not very relevant here on security.stackechange.

Note that (unless you go down the [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) route) the access would probably have to be granted based on the MAC address of the client device - which can be faked.

You'll need a [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) server configured to serve short leases, and a webserver with a logic tier which can autenticate users / payments and pass the IP address / MAC address to the device gating access to the Internet - if it were me, I'd just allow HTTP and HTTPS and control this via a proxy such as [Squid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_%28software%29). The advantage of using the HTTP proxy is that you can easily redirect unauthenticated clients back to the login page on your server (you can't do this in a firewall). Note that you'll need to set up the device to [transparently reroute HTTP via the proxy](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-6.html).

This won't work for protocols like [POP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol), [IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) and [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) - but you could publish the same information to a script controlling the firewall - indeed you could configure [Fail2ban](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail2ban) to work the opposite way it usually does!

Comment: Don't you mean yes, really?